# Java Runtime Class - Unable to cd in cmd Prompt

Tags: java, runtime.exec

This program is to create a server certificate from java without opening a command prompt(at least manually) This code executes successfully, but i can't see my file "server.jks" neither in the "cd"ed  directory nor in the default directory where cmd loads up(c:\Documents and Settings\administrator). I am more interested in generating in a specified directory. help me alter my code to do that.

```
  public class SslKeytool
 {
public void createServerCertificate(String dn, String alias, String validity, String keystoreName, String keypass, String storepass, String drive, String path)
{
    try
    {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        String result;
        result = "keytool -genkeypair ";
        result = result + "-alias " + alias + " ";

        result = result + "-keyalg RSA -dname " + dn + " -validity " + validity + " -keypass" + keypass + " -keystorename " + keystoreName
                + " -storepass" + storepass;
        runtime.exec("cmd " + drive + ":");
        runtime.exec("cmd cd " + path);
        runtime.exec("cmd " + result);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Whoa! Something went wrong! please make sure that you read the API ");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    SslKeytool obj = new SslKeytool();
    obj.createServerCertificate("CN=LCMS,OU=Software Solutions,O=Live Connections,L=Chennai,S=TamilNadu,C=Ind", "servercert", "365", "abc.jks", "lcmsauth"
            , "lcmsauth", "f", "/keytest");

}
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this post http://blog.thilinamb.com/2010/01/how-to-generate-self-signed.html

Comment: I know how to create a self signed certificate, but i wanna do it through java and dynamically.

Comment: Have you considered this post then? http://blog.thilinamb.com/2010/01/how-to-generate-self-signed.html